# Subtrair dias a data atual com PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço para diminuir, por exemplo assim:
$dataAtual = '20/02/2016';
$dataSubtracao = '18/02/2016';

$calc = $dataAtual - $dataSubtracao;
//Como resultado eu queria que retornasse o número 2 (tipo, 2 dias de diferença)

Sei que esse exemplo vai dar errado, mas eu quero que no resultado retorne o valor inteiro da diferença entre as duas datas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [date_sub](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_sub.asp) conforme a documentação.

Outra opção é a implementação convertendo as datas para segundos, subtraindo os segundos e em seguida convertendo o resultado para o tipo data novamente.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d'); //recebe a data atual

$seconds = strtotime($today); //converte para segundos

$diff_date = date("Y-m-d",($seconds - 86400)); //subtrai um dia (valor em segundos) e converte para um objeto do tipo data
```

---

**Nota:**
*O intervalo válido de um timestamp é tipicamente de Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT até Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (Estas são datas que correspondem aos valores máximos e mínimos para um inteiro assinado de 32-bit.)*